# Preventing File Downloads in AWS SageMaker Studio JupyterLab (Version 4)

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, jupyter-lab, amazon-sagemaker-studio

How can I prevent users from downloading files (such as CSV or IPYNB) from AWS SageMaker Studio's JupyterLab (version 4)?

I've attempted to use lifecycle configurations, but users are able to select "no script" for the lifecycle configuration when starting the JupyterLab session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the LCC as the default (DefaultResourceSpec in [JupyterLabAppSetting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_JupyterLabAppSettings.html)), the LCC will run even if the user chooses 'No Script'.

If you'd like to enforce this LCC, make sure that they cannot choose a *different* LCC when creating a Space and running the app.